# Image optimization: Photoshop CS6 vs jpegtran / OptiPNG

Tags: jpeg, png, image-editing, photoshop-cs6

Is there any difference in terms of algorithm for optimization between Photoshop's Shift+Alt+S (save for web) and jpegtran's `-optimize` and `-progressive`?

It seems my images are not reduced (or reduced by 500 Bytes at most, or even increased in size sometimes) by jpegtran after I save it through Photoshop.

I seem to get somewhat better results with OptiPNG though, but in most cases there's no difference as well.